# Values sorted as String but I want to sort them as number in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I read in python a log that contains name, memory, ncalls for each row
and save this as tuple list where each element is a tuple *(name, memory, ncalls)*
sometimes need to sort the list according name other times according memory or ncalls.
The problem if I simply use the code

```
 mylist=sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(2))
```

the list is sorted using the desired parameter but python consider the parameter like a String and I get this result

```
item3, 45, 1
item1, 4, 12
item4, 65, 3
item2, 65, 5
```

the desired result would be

```
item3, 45, 1
item4, 65, 3
item2, 65, 5
item1, 4, 12
```

because 3 and 5 are smaller than 12

How could I solve this without change the way i save the list?

Comment: Why does string sorting assume that `12` is larger than `3`?

Comment: Please, rename your variable - `list` is a built-in function and you're overriding it with `list = sorted(...)`

Comment: Your output suggests `itemgetter(2))` does not mean each last number in your input, as Selcuk suggests 3 would not come before 12

Comment: @Selcuk string sorting doesn't take in account numeric size and assumes that 1 and 2 are alphabetically before 3. Why someone has downvoted my question?

Comment: @AndreaF I am aware of that, but in your example it looks like `5 > 12 > 3 > 1` which does not look correct either with integer sorting or string sorting.

Comment: What are you talking about? In my sample there is the result that I get with the linecode reported that uses alphabetical order and the result that I want to achieve as I have said. alphabetically 1 is before 2, 2 before 3, 3 before 5 this is the reason of the output.

Comment: String sorting would have resulted in `1, 12, 3, 5`.

Comment: @AndreaF You should really re-read _your question_ and _all the other comments_ before replying. Anyways, if you think that your problem is solved then never mind.

Comment: ops, I'm sorry you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to define key as a lambda converting the third item to int:

```
sorted_data = sorted(list, key=lambda t: int(t[2]))
```

Comment: Good answer, but please don't use list as a variable name.