# Sort a list of strings containing numbers at the start of the list by the numbers in the strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of `HTML` files in my directory obtained using the `glob` and they have the pattern `numb-filenames`. I would like to `sort` the `list` by the numbers

The `len` of the `string` is 76. I could not copy all of it but here are a few of them:

```
['50-Rcompat.html',
 '51-tang.html',
 '52-rectgw.html',
 '53-wea.html',
 '54-PTect.html',
 '55-R+V Allg.html',
 '56-SafetyCa.html',
 '57-TEI.html',
 '58-TAS.html',
 '59-TrPr.html',
 '6-sde.html',
 '60-weac.html',
 '61-WKra.html',
 '62-KCV .html',
 '63-Wdenbu.html',
 '64-TGARA.html',
 '65-BiV.html',
 '66-BURG.html',
 '67-richI.html',
 '7-pril.html',
 '8-spario.html',
 '9-Weal.html']
```

Here is my attempt:

```
sorted(df, key=lambda x: re.findall("\d+",x))
```

Comment: Your solution is *almost* there: `re.findall` will return a list of strings so they'll still sort as strings, you then need to convert them to number so that they sort numerically. A full blown `findall` is also overkill since you have a single number, `search/match` or even a simple `str.split` would do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Values sorted as String but I want to sort them as number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399303/values-sorted-as-string-but-i-want-to-sort-them-as-number-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))
```

We are splitting the string at '-' and fetching the first part which consists of number in string format - then casting it to int type and using it as a key to sort the list.

Comment: Might be better to do `split('-', 1)` since you just want the first part of the split.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sorted(df, key=lambda x: int(x[:x.find('-')]))
```

That will sort you all the files base on the number in the beginning of the file name. 
Output

```
['6-sde.html',
 '7-pril.html',
 '8-spario.html',
 '9-Weal.html',
 '50-Rcompat.html',
 '51-tang.html',
 '52-rectgw.html',
 '53-wea.html',
 '54-PTect.html',
 '55-R+V Allg.html',
 '56-SafetyCa.html',
 '57-TEI.html',
 '58-TAS.html',
 '59-TrPr.html',
 '60-weac.html',
 '61-WKra.html',
 '62-KCV .html',
 '63-Wdenbu.html',
 '64-TGARA.html',
 '65-BiV.html',
 '66-BURG.html',
 '67-richI.html']
```